# Why would a paper uploaded to Academia.edu have words whited out?

Tags: publications, online-publication

A paper I looked up on Academia.edu today turned out to be a scan of pages in which many words have been whited-out with typists' correction fluid. This is a typical sentence:

> Unfortunately, the Dirac-Baez Determinant is ill-conditioned for assessing the isomorphism structure of Pauling's high-order valence-bond bundles. [WHITE-OUT] Mac Lane's 2-categorification of taxogellation coefficients on the [WHITE-OUT] [WHITE-OUT] hints at such an outcome ([WHITE-OUT] 1972b; also 1973), while Gordon Pask's electro-neural–swarm dimensionality compression (Pask 1961), as well as Stafford Beer's POSIWID analysis of [WHITE-OUT] (Beer 1972), and Ron Atkin's multidimensional [WHITE-OUT] (Atkins 1972), confirm it for non-dense *επι*–recodings.

(I have altered words so that I don't identify the person who uploaded the paper.)

The paper is a chapter of a recently published book, and I haven't found any open-access copies. Is this a case of what WBT describes in an answer to [Citing paywalled articles accessed via illegal web sharing](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/125570/citing-paywalled-articles-accessed-via-illegal-web-sharing/125721#125721)? WBT says that "Sometimes, the differences [between official paywalled copies of papers and unofficial free ones] are honeypots intentionally inserted by publishers designed to get the message out that only official sites can be relied upon for accurate information."

To clarify following a comment: knzhou suggests this is likely to be a scanning or rendering error. I was going to post a screenshot, but don't have enough reputation. It's immediately obvious to anyone who has used these correction fluids — which I have when cartooning — that that's what they are. Give-aways include the colour, thickness diminishing towards the long edges, brush streaks on the surface, and the way the marks follow the words. I'm not *worried* about this, though it's annoying to lose the information in the publication, but I am curious. I've never seen this before.

Comment: It's more likely to be a PDF rendering error or scanning error, especially if it's from a bootleg site like Academic.edu. I've never seen a real example of what WBT is talking about -- and if there were such examples, it wouldn't be this obvious.

Comment: We are Academia SE, not Academia.edu.

Comment: scaaahu — but Academia SE has other questions about Academia.edu . Are you saying I shouldn't have posted this one?

Comment: So why not ask on Academia.edu?

Comment: White out immediately makes me think of originally classified, then redacted and released documents. But that seems an unlikely explanation for a chapter of a recent book.

Comment: Someone used a highlighter in the original book, then used whiteout?